# one click to find bean definition in different spring configure file in Eclipse

Tags: spring, eclipse, plugins, keyboard-shortcuts

I am reading our code with Eclipse and found one annoying thing that really slow down my steps.

When I read spring configure file, if one bean have reference bean, I will go on to find the ref bean definition by Ctrl+K.

If the ref bean definition was in the same configure file, that works good.

But if the ref bean is in another configure file, I need to Ctrl+H to search all the XML files to find it which is very slow and need to find the real definition file manually as there will have many matches.

So do we have any way to find the spring ref bean definition in another file more easily? Shortcut key or eclipse plugin both are welcome.

Comment: Have you tried this one out https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/spring-ide ?

Comment: You can Press Ctrl key and click the bean class name in bean definition link. And try to use SpringToolSuite STS rather than eclipse.

Comment: Need to jump to another configure file and find the ref bean definition by one click, Can spring-ide or SpringToolSuite do that? What's the shortcut key? In my company, I need some process to install software and plugin. So want to know it previously.